# Query to get the min date for the duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my query, if there duplicate records I need to filter based on dates.

```sql
select
    X.[po number],
    (X.[ grn number]),
    (X.[grn docentry]),
    (X.ItemCode),
    (X.[grn total]),
    (X.tax),
    (x.DocDate)[docdate]
from (
    SELECT  Distinct
        T0.[DocNum] [po number],
        T3.[DocNum] [ grn number],
        T3.DocEntry [grn docentry],
        T1.ItemCOde,
        (T3.DocDate),
        CASE WHEN T3.DocCur != 'SGD'
          then (T4.PriceBefDi * T4.Quantity)
          ELSE T4.LineTotal
        END [grn total],
        CASE WHEN T3.DocCur != 'SGD'
          THEN T4.VatSumFrgn
          ELSE T4.VatSum
        END as [tax]
    FROM OPOR T0
    INNER JOIN POR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
    INNER JOIN  PDN1 T4 on  T1.DocEntry = T4.BaseEntry and T1.LineNum = T4.BaseLine 
    INNER JOIN  OPDN T3 on T3.DocEntry = T4.DocEntry
)X
where X.[po number] in (37199, 37431, 37163, 37163, 37548)
  and X.[grn total] in (1350.0000, 650.0000, 140.0000, 372.0000, 685.0000)
```

Below is my result set. if there are similar item codes, amount, tax amount. I need get only one record based on the minimum date for those matching. The highlighted red color must not show in the result set.

[image]

The actual output is like below:

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Whitespace doesn't cost, you know. And those are some weird names: why put spaces in column names, and why not [use better aliases than `T1 T2 T3`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)?

Comment: @Charlieface well noted

Answer (score 0):

One way is

```
select top(1) with ties *
from ( 
 -- your original query
) t
order by row_number() over(partition by ItemCode, [grn total], tax  order by docdate)
```

Comment: If you are going to use `top (1) with ties`, then a subquery is unnecessary.  In my mind, that is the reason why to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate and select - what looks like - the `min` of each group:

```
select X.[po number], Min(X.[grn number])[grn number], Min(X.[grn docentry])[grn docentry], X.ItemCode, X.[grn total], X.tax, Min(X.DocDate) [docdate]  from (
    select  distinct T0.[DocNum] [po number], T3.[DocNum] [ grn number], T3.DocEntry [grn docentry], T1.ItemCOde, T3.DocDate, 
    case when T3.DocCur != 'SGD' then (T4.PriceBefDi * T4.Quantity) else T4.LineTotal end [grn total] , 
    case when T3.DocCur != 'SGD'  then T4.VatSumFrgn else T4.VatSum end as [tax]
    from OPOR T0 
    inner join POR1 T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
    inner join  PDN1 T4 on  T1.DocEntry = T4.BaseEntry and T1.LineNum = T4.BaseLine 
    inner join  OPDN T3 on T3.DocEntry = T4.DocEntry
)X 
where X.[po number] in (37199, 37431, 37163, 37163, 37548) and X.[grn total] in (1350.0000, 650.0000, 140.0000, 372.0000, 685.0000)
group by  X.[po number], X.ItemCode, X.[grn total], X.tax
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` for and set `HAVING` clause `MIN(x.DocDate)`.
I guess that your unique column is `x.ItemCode` and add the rest of column.

Sample:

```
GROUP BY x.ItemCode
HAVING MIN(x.DocDate)
```